# Find $\gcd (a,2^a)$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z_+}$

Tags: number-theory

We know that if $a$ is even then

> $(a,2^a)=a$ since $a\le 2^a $ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z} $

and

if $a$ is odd then

> $(a,2^a)=1$

$\square$

Is this enough,and how would we work out

> $(a,2^a-1)$

using the following equality
$(2^m-1,2^n-1)=(2^{(m,n)}-1)$

Comment: the first sentence is wrong

Comment: Well second inequality is obvious. By the way you meant to say $a\in\mathbb{Z}_+$?

Comment: Yes $a$ in the set of positive integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessarily true that $(a,2^a) = a$ if $a$ is even, (consider $(6,2^6) = 2$). Since the prime factorization of $2^a$ is just a product of a bunch of twos, the gcd of $2^a$ with any number less than it will just be the number of twos in the prime factorization of that number.

Comment: How can we express that,Mathematically.I guess its equal to $(a,2^a=)a$ iff $a$ is of the form $2^b$

Comment: Yeah, mathematically I can't really think of too slick of a way to say it either. I guess I would say $(a,2^a) = 2^k$, where $k$ is the maximum integer $k$ such that $2^k \mid a$.